# Android Studio v1.3 Checking for Unchecked Permissions Usage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

The following picture shows an example screenshot of the error message from the static analysis from the relevant Google I/O 2015 video. (link here: https://youtu.be/f7ihSQ44WO0?t=27m12s)

[image]

And I wish to be able to run the same static analysis that will show me all of these problem areas in the app I'm working on. However, I have spent the whole afternoon running all kinds of code analysis through Android Studio with the end effect of making the code-base look so much prettier, but still coming no closer to discovering how to do what I initially sought to do.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to run the static analysis in question?

Thanks!

Android Studio Version: 1.3 
Android Studio Build Number: AI-141.2117773
Android SDK Tools: MNC Revision 2

Comment: Android Studio 1.3 claims to have the feature "Missing permission checks and unhandled revocable permission checks." But saying it's there doens't mean it's there! https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio13betaavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I realized why it isn't working in Android Studio 1.3.

Our app is written with a lot of exception handling in case of unexpected errors. The permissions check implemented in Android Studio 1.3 counts uses of these permissions wrapped within `try { } catch (Exception e) { }` blocks as being handled.

So, for those of us who were liberally using `try-catch` blocks in our code, we are SOL for now.

EDIT: This issue is fixed in Android Studio v1.4 :D

Comment: Its fixed since Android Studio v1.4, so it should work.